# Arranging a label and table side-by-side with the label being fixed width, and the table taking up the remaining 100%?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I know there are tons of CSS side-by-side positioning questions, but I have a unique scenario that I haven't seen any answer that works.

I am stuck with the following HTML block, that I cannot change:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <label>...</label>
        <table>...</table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "outer" div has a fixed width that can change at runtime. The "inner" div can repeat any number of times, and has a width of 100%.

I need to have each `<label>` element take up a fixed width of 150px, with the `<table>` element taking up the rest (ie, 100% of the remaining space).

No matter how I try to float the elements, etc, I can't get it to work correctly. Also, this application will only be used on machines with latest versions of Chrome / Firefox, so IE backwards-compatibility is not an issue.

Thanks!

Comment: A `label` is used to identify an interactive `form` element, not to label arbitrary elements. You should, probably, be using the [`caption`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption) element in this situation.

Comment: Can the HTML be changed at all?  If the `table` was in it's own `div` it would be easy

Comment: @davidpauljunior MAYBE :) , but management would very much prefer not to have a div just for the table. However, can you post your solution with a div as an answer? If I get no real solutions for an un-dived table, I will choose your answer (assuming it works).

Comment: @DavidThomas No, unfortunately the label is required, because this actually IS part of a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a padding left to the `.inner` and then negatively margin the `label` back into that space.

Like this:

```
.inner {
  padding-left: 150px;
}

label {
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  float: left;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**http://jsbin.com/IdayeTOp/1/edit**

Comment: Wow, nice, simple solution that I haven't thought of. This is great, thanks! :)